# adding Dictionary(Object) to a MutableArray Objective C

Tags: objective-c

Really new to Objective C, I'm trying to add these objects to a MutableArray.  My problem is this, when I'm adding new books to the array by specifying the name of the book like this:

```
[self.bookData addObject:[self newBookWithTitle:@"some book" andAuthor:@"some author"]];
```

it works.  However, I want to use 2 variables I've created to get the title and author but I keep getting an error saying that it expects a ":"  from the code below (inputTitle and inputAuthor are my variables that grab from the textFields

```
[self.bookData addObject:[self newBookWithTitle:@"%@", _inputTitle andAuthor:@"%@", inputAuthor]];
```

Sorry, I've looked all over but can't find out whats wrong with my syntax and where to put the : it says it needs. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: strings and methods aren't magic. they don't know anything about printf-style string formatting, and methods are not variadic unkess declared so. Hint: `+[NSString stringWithFormat:]` is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `@"%@",` in both places of the second line. Just pass `_inputTitle` and `inputAuthor` as-is assuming they are `NSString` objects.

```
[self.bookData addObject:[self newBookWithTitle:_inputTitle andAuthor:inputAuthor]];
```

BTW - do yourself a favor and make your code easier to read as well as easier to debug. Split the line in two:

```
NSString *book = [self newBookWithTitle:_inputTitle andAuthor:inputAuthor];
[self.bookData addObject:book];
```

I'm assuming `newBookWithTitle:andAuthor:` returns an `NSString`. Adjust as needed.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I thought you needed those @"@" in some form or another.

Comment: Nope. If you wanted to format values or combine them with other values then you can use `NSString stringWithFormat:` to build a single string from other values. But if you simply want to pass a single `NSString` variable to an `NSString` parameter, pass it as-is.